# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clicked' again

Tags: python, pyqt5, attributeerror

Hi can anyone help me for this problem `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clicked'`

my code is :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500,250,300,400)
        self.setWindowTitle("SMURF")
        self.UI()
        self.show()
    def UI(self):
        self.text=QLabel("hi bitxg",self).move(150,100)
        b1=QPushButton("B1",self).move(130,120)
        b2=QPushButton("B2",self).move(170,120)
        b1.clicked.connect(self.b1f)
        b2.clicked.connect(self.b2f)    
    def b1f(self):
        self.text.setText("FIRST")
    def b2f(self):
        self.text.setText("SECOND")            

App=QApplication(sys.argv)
window=Window()
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `.move()` on the same line as initializing the widgets. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/16775594) deals with a very similar problem in `tkinter`. Apparently, it's a common GUI-programming problem.

Comment: The real issue here is that you're not using layouts. There's very rarely any genuine need to use absoule positioning with child widgets. I suggest you read this [pyqt5 layout management tutorial](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I don't think that can be considered a "common GUI-programming problem". The function chaining pattern is to be expected only for very specific types of objects, and for which it makes sense to *always* return the (eventually) modified object. This is a rare requirement not only for GUI programming.

Comment: @musicamante If you kept an eye on all the [tag:tkinter] questions like I do, you would see how common it is (hence my use of "apparently"). For instance, there are over 300 linked questions to the question I linked to in my above comment, and many of them are duplicates. I haven't seen very many similar questions that _didn't_ have to do with GUI programming, but I won't deny that they exist. GUI programming is just where I see this problem the most.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to split this up:

```
b1=QPushButton("B1",self).move(130,120)
b2=QPushButton("B2",self).move(170,120)
```

Becomes:

```
b1=QPushButton("B1",self)
b1.move(130,120)

b2=QPushButton("B2",self)
b2.move(170,120)
```

Currently, you are instantiating an anonymous `QPushButton` object, and then binding the object returned by calling that anonymous object's `move` method to `b1` and `b2`, which will be `None`.